# Outlook addin development

Tags: javascript, c#, outlook, add-in, office365

I'm going to develop an add in for outlook. There is outlook desktop app and outlook web app. I found these two links for development ,

- [Outlook web app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220060.aspx)
- [Outlook desktop app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx)

Do I need to develop separate add in for each. Or is there any way to develop a single add in and deploy in both?

Advice on how to deploy these two would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The first one (now called Office addin) works both on the Web (OWA) and in the desktop version of Outlook. But it is very limited - in the current version it is really a fancy preview pane working in the context of the currently selected/viewed message/appointment/contact/task.

The second one only works on the desktop, but the API is very rich.

It all comes down to what exactly your addin is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to develop separate add in for each

Yes, you need to develop a separate solution if you want to get a COM add-in and Mail App.

> Or is there any way to develop a single add in and deploy in both?

No, they are based on entirely separate technologies and can't be deployed using the single installer.

See [Selecting an API or Technology for Developing Outlook Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg608200(v=office.14).aspx) for more information.